# Run OpenVPN service on connection to internet

Tags: internet, vpn, openvpn

How can I make a OpenVPN run automatically whenever my system is connected to the internet?

Comment: Please use "OpenVPN" instead of "VPN". From [your other question](http://askubuntu.com/q/28733/6969), I guess you really meant "OpenVPN".

Comment: @Lekensteyn, it would benefit more people if there was a way to connect to all types of VPN.

Comment: that depends on the configuration, when using Network Manager, you can check "Automatically connect" on a VPN.

Comment: @Lekensteyn, that never worked for me with either PPTP or OpenVPN. And since you're replying to my post, there's no need to tag me. When it's not the post of the user you're replying to, then you need to tag @[user].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When OpenVPN starts with a VPN (`/etc/openvpn/*.conf`), it will continue to try connecting to the server. No worries :)

Comment: So I just need to have OpenVPN on my startup list?

Comment: When installing OpenVPN, it puts a startup script at `/etc/init.d/openvpn`. This script starts any VPN configurations defined in `/etc/openvpn/*.conf`. The packaga manager already took care of starting the services, all you have to do after installing OpenVPN is creating a configuration file in `/etc/openvpn/*.conf`, which you've already done.