# OpenVPN & Network-Manager-OpenVPN & Connecting to Internet ipv4

Tags: network-manager, 17.10, openvpn

I'm trying to route internet traffic through my vpn. I've set up everything using a tutorial. Now, I've heard that OpenVPN can only handle either ipv4 OR ipv6. So I wanna stick with ipv4. I disabled ipv6 in the network manager on my pc, but now, ipv6 websites are still sent over ipv6 without the VPN. How can I prevent this?

Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind disabling IPv6 entirely then you could try this answer [here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/441122/512236)

Do `ifconfig` first and check if you still have an IPv6 address, if you do then it's still active, if not then something else is going on...

There is always 1 IPv6 address, ignore the fe80 one, if you have a second then it is still active.
[image]

You could also trying pinging an ipv6 address to see if you still get a reply

`ping6 2607:f8b0:4003:c00::6a`

Comment: hm, i have another IPv6 address. but the one from my ISP. Is there no way to disable it on both, my pc and mobile? :) Just so all network traffic is routed over the vpn? I mean, that's what the vpn is for.

Comment: If you're looking to route more devices than just your PC then maybe looking into setting up a VPN on your router will be more appropriate?
It's also possible you could disable IPv6 on your router.

Comment: no i have openvpn on my server. ubuntu 16.04. i have both of my devices connected to the vpn its just the problem, that ipv6 is used, instead of ipv4 for surfing the internet ;D

Comment: Yes, so if you still have an IPv6 address as you mentioned earlier try following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/441122/512236) guide to disable it.