# how to run an --up script using network-manager-openvpn?

Tags: scripts, network-manager, openvpn

I'm using network-manager-openvpn (w Ubuntu 14.04) to manage VPN connections (client end).

I need to run a script when a VPN is activated to fix some routing issues.   I know how to do this using openvpn config options ( --script-security 2 --up /script.. ) but I can not figure out a sensible way with network-manager in the mix.

Is there a "recommended" way to approach this without reverting to pre-network-manager config files?

Or is there a suggested way to detect that the VPN has come up and hence triggering an action (something a bit more elegant than firing off a cron to look at the status every minute would be appreciated!)?

Answer (score 6):

Add your script to `/etc/network/if-up.d/` directory.

All the scripts in this directory will run when a connection or vpn connection starts (up|vpn-up).

As noted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28733/how-do-i-run-a-script-after-openvpn-has-connected-successfully) network-manager-openvpn does not provide such functionality, you otherwise have to use openvpn directly.

Because this directory load scripts on connection and vpn connection, your script may require additional checks.

Take a look at the file `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown`. You can see the which directories are used when connection changes.

I use the `/etc/network/if-post-down.d/` directory with a script to disconnect in the event my vpn connection fails.

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Bump this subject because I have same problem.. When OpenVPN call the "up" script, it gives some dynamic arguments ; how to get them in [...]/if-up.d/my-custom-script ?