# Can I have only one program access my VPN?

Tags: network-manager, vpn

Currently I have two computers, both running Ubuntu. Both computers connect to the same ISP, but with one I use a VPN service. For reasons not relevant to this question, I am considering getting rid of the VPN computer and consolidating all my tasks to the other computer. However, I would still like to use the VPN service for some programs, but not all.

With my current set up, on the computer I am keeping, I can click on the network icon in my panel (Gnome Classic) and toggle my VPN on and off. However, this is global and affects all internet connections from all programs. This is not ideal. The VPN service, while offering privacy and access to services otherwise unavailable in my area, is slower than my non-VPN connection.

What I'm after is a situation like this: I'm using Firefox, and I'm also using Clementine for streaming radio. I then want to open Chrome and have Chrome access the internet via the VPN. Ideally, Chrome is set up so that it automatically uses the VPN without me having to turn it on and off. However, I want Firefox and Clementine to continue accessing the net directly, not switch over to the VPN service.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Have you checked this => [Exempt programs from using active VPN connection](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26870/exempt-programs-from-using-active-vpn-connection)

Comment: @Achu, thank you for that link. I had not seen it before. However, now that I am looking at it, it seems to presumes a fair amount of expert knowledge. I'm hoping for more of a laymans explanation.

Comment: Doesn't your vpn provider have proxy support?

Comment: @davidbaumann, apparently they provide a "SOCKS5 Proxy". I have never set up a proxy before, though, and I'm barely aware of what it is. I've seen the option to set up a proxy in programs like Firefox. Are you suggesting I can use a proxy from within the program to access my VPN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a virtual box as replacement for the "vpn computer". In this box, you just install vpn again and it's very uncomplicated for you, as the usage is just the same as before!  [VirtualBox usage in wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/Activities/Classroom/Saucy/Virtualbox)

Comment: Given the anonymity issue in your other answer, this looks like the way to go. I am currently looking into virtual computer options, and trying to find the easiest to set up.

Comment: Just install Virtual Box, create a new Box, assign hdd, mem and cpu cores to it and then boot it from an iso!

Comment: This method does indeed turn out to be the easiest, at least for my needs. I installed Lubuntu with Virtualbox, and it is not too taxing on my system, and allows me to separate out different programs accessing the net by VPN as hoped.

Answer (score 1):

Just configure the apps, that have used the vpn before, to use the proxy the vpn provider supports.[Firefox example](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/faq/id-1847788/configure-proxy-settings-mozilla-firefox.html)
As long as you are not using it for anonymity, there's no concern about it.

There are many plugins for firefox which helps setting up: [FoxyProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/)

Comment: Thank you for this response. Can you explain what you mean by "as long as you are not using it for anonymity"? Anonymity is part of the reason I use a VPN, so what kind of anonymity issues are we talking about?

Comment: Usually, the connection to a proxy is not encrypted. So your isp/ government firewall can track your activity.